# How to share internet from iPad to Ubuntu via USB cable

Tags: usb, ipad, tethering

How to share the internet of my iPad Air with my Ubuntu PC?

On the iPad I navigate to: Settings -> Personal Hotspot, there it displays:

> TO CONNECT USING USB
>    1 . Plug iPad into your computer
>
> 2 . Choose iPad from the list of network services in your settings

Where can I find `your settings`?
Is it the settings of the iPad or the settings of Ubunutu?

Comment: I guess it is ubuntu, but not sure if this will be shown in the networks, but try it